# Cocoa Application Finished Launch

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way to tell if a Cocoa application, such as Safari, has finished launching and able to respond?
I know it's easy to do using delegates within the actual code but that isn't possible for what I'm doing.

Thanks

Comment: What platform, Mac OS X or iPhone?

Comment: Well that's the thing... I posted it in Cocoa but I am actually not trying to find a Cocoa solution, just a way to tell if a Cocoa app has successfully launched

Comment: Tell if a Cocoa app has successfully launched? Normally if you can click things on the interface, it means awakeFromNib has finished and the app has finished launching. Is there more specifics you are able to give out to help us give a better answer?

Comment: JXA example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49560860/199296

Answer (score 8):

Check out NSWorkspace and NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification. Something like this:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidLaunch:) name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification object:nil]
```

The NSNotification object passed to the specified method will contain information about what application launched, its path, etc. For example:

```
- (void)appDidLaunch:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSLog(@"app launched: %@", [note userInfo]);
}
```

EDIT: this is for desktop cocoa applications only - I'm fairly sure this is impossible in Cocoa Touch. Just clarifying that.