# Get notified of application launch on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit, nsworkspace

I want to be notified when an application is started on Mac OSX. I found [Cocoa Application Finished Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550080/cocoa-application-finished-launch) and that seemed to answer my question, but the callback method `appDidLaunch` is not being called when Preview get's launched.

Here's what I have so far,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Appkit/Appkit.h>

@interface test_case: NSObject
-(void)run;
@end

@implementation test_case: NSObject

- (void)appDidLaunch:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSLog(@"app launched: %@", [note userInfo]);
}

-(void)run {
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidLaunch:) name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification object:nil];

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/nah/Desktop/bsd_hacks.pdf"
        withApplication:@"Preview"];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        test_case * t = [[test_case alloc] init];

        [t run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So why is `appDidLaunch` not being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application ends execution (exit `main` function) before you have a chance to receive notification. Moreover, you need to correctly setup main run loop to handle notification. Usually, `NSApplicationMain` call does all the application setup for you. So, the easiest way to fix an issue, is next change in `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        test_case * t = [[test_case alloc] init];
        [t run];
        return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect a launch of a **background application**, e.g. a menu bar application like Viscosity etc.? Apple says that "the system does not post [NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification] for background apps or for apps that have the `LSUIElement` key in their `Info.plist` file. If you want to know when all apps (including background apps) are launched or terminated, use key-value observing to monitor the value returned by the `runningApplications` method."

I would like to add that to my listener posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52710089/6699322