# macOS: Detect all application launches including background apps?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, command-line-interface, nsworkspace

Newbie here. I'm trying to create a small listener for application launches, and I already have this:

```
// almon.m

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

@interface almon: NSObject {}
-(id) init;
-(void) launchedApp: (NSNotification*) notification;
@end

@implementation almon
-(id) init {
  NSNotificationCenter * notify
    = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

  [notify addObserver: self
          selector:    @selector(launchedApp:)
          name:        @"NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification"
          object:      nil
  ];
  fprintf(stderr,"Listening...\n");
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
  fprintf(stderr,"Stopping...\n");
  return self;
}

-(void) launchedApp: (NSNotification*) notification {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo]; // read full application launch info
  NSString* AppPID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"]; // parse for AppPID
  int killPID = [AppPID intValue]; // define integer from NSString
  kill((killPID), SIGSTOP); // interrupt app launch
  NSString* AppPath = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationPath"]; // read application path
  NSString* AppBundleID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationBundleIdentifier"]; // read BundleID
  NSString* AppName = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"]; // read AppName
  NSLog(@":::%@:::%@:::%@:::%@", AppPID, AppPath, AppBundleID, AppName);
}
@end

int main( int argc, char ** argv) {
  [[almon alloc] init];
  return 0;
}
// build: gcc -Wall almon.m -o almon -lobjc -framework Cocoa
// run: ./almon
```

Note: when I build it, it will run fine, but if you do it with Xcode 10 on High Sierra, you will get `ld` warnings, which you can ignore, however.

**My question:** Is there a way to also detect a launch of a **background application**, e.g. a menu bar application like Viscosity etc.? Apple says that

> the system does not post
>   [NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification] for background apps or
>   for apps that have the `LSUIElement` key in their `Info.plist` file.
>   If you want to know when all apps (including background apps) are
>   launched or terminated, use key-value observing to monitor the value
>   returned by the `runningApplications` method.

Here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacewilllaunchapplicationnotification?language=objc

I would at least try to add support for background apps etc. to the listener, but I don't know how to go about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As the document suggests, you use Key-Value Observing to observe the `runningApplications` property of the shared workspace object:

```
static const void *kMyKVOContext = (void*)&kMyKVOContext;


[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] addObserver:self
                                forKeyPath:@"runningApplications"
                                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew // maybe | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
                                   context:kMyKVOContext];
```

Then, you would implement the observation method (using Xcode's ready-made snippet):

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{
    if (context != kMyKVOContext)
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        return;
    }

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"runningApplications"])
    {
        <#code to be executed when runningApplications has changed#>
    }
}
```

Comment: a few confused about kMyKVOContext